# Problem with differencing trend-stationary processes?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, trend, differences

I have read somewhere (possibly in Hayashi's Econometrics text) that it can be problematic to work with differenced trend-stationary processes. I have not been able to find the exact source again and I do not remember in which context this was stated to be problematic. Can someone make sense of this?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/461594/is-a-time-trend-a-substitute-for-first-differencing   (and its links!)